# How can I get CI of extracted fixed effect estimates from a linear mixed effects model?

Tags: r, lme4

I have a linear mixed effects model that looks like this:

```
model.1 <- lmer(x ~ 0 + treatment + (1|block), data)
```

I pulled out the fixed effect estimates from the model:

```
data$FittedValues <- fixef(model.1)
```

I made a distribution histogram of the fitted values and I need to know the 95% CI of the fitted values. I tried confint() which gives a CI for each treatment, but what I need a CI for the entire set of fitted values.  I can run a t.test on the fitted values but I don't think this gives me the correct answer.

```
t.test(FittedValues, data = data, 
   alternative = 'two.sided',    
   conf.level = 0.95, 
   na.rm = TRUE)
```

I am new to stats and R, but I searched for quite some time and couldn't find an answer.  Please excuse me if this is too simple of a questions for this board.

Comment: I find your question confusing because it is not sufficiently clear for what exactly you desire a confidence interval. Population level predictions or subject level predictions?

Comment: Sorry, population level.

Comment: Try the `FEsim` function in the `merTools` package, which provides the fixed effect from the posterior distribution of the fitted `merMod` object. It even has a nice plot method to display the results graphically.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that.